# hosts file rebuild after a while

Tags: hosts

I got a strange problem with my hosts file on windows machine. I save it with some default ip's - hostnames and after some time I notice again that some of the hosts have again tagged with the # symbol infront of them? Why is that happening and how can I prevent it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many anti-virus solutions now-days respawn your host file if it gets altered. I have encountered this situation.

What you most likely need to do is configure your AV (via local or central policy) to ignore host file location. That way, you can change it and it will remain changed.

Comment: Thank you! I think this was the problem. So easy yet never have thought of this solution!